# ColdFusion - Processing results from two simultaneous XML queries?

Tags: xml, arrays, loops, coldfusion, struct

I need to build a page that lists each committee member for a given committee, their position, their email and phone number. This data is exposed over XML webservice. One table contains committee data (member name, position), the other table contains individual data (email, phone). I tried getting the data in a single query using a join, but the API evidently does not support that. It does provide a "MultiQuery" method that allows for a number of discrete queries to be run, though, so that is what I am using.

I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705162/coldfusion-how-to-loop-through-xml-output-and-adding-to-struct-or-array) earlier, which in fact uses the same XML and same general setup. Peter Boughton and others were very helpful, and their suggestions are working great. The difference between then and now is, then I only needed the committee data. Now I need both committee and individual data, and that's where I am stuck.

The results from the two queries come out in two sections -- one object, but two "ArrayOfanyType" sections. Both "sections" are broken down and contained in a single array:

```
<cfset keyValue = xmlSearch(soapBody,"//*[local-name()='KeyValueOfstringanyType']") />
```

I can use a brute-force approach to loop through this array to add data to a struct:

```
<cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#arrayLen(keyValue)#">
<cfif keyValue[i].Key.xmlText EQ 'Member_Name'>
    <cfset memberName = keyValue[i].Value.xmlText>
</cfif>
<cfif keyValue[i].Key.xmlText EQ 'Position_Name'>
    <cfset positionName = keyValue[i].Value.xmlText>
</cfif>
<cfif keyValue[i].Key.xmlText EQ 'Member_Guid'>
    <cfset memberGuid = keyValue[i].Value.xmlText>
</cfif>
<cfif keyValue[i].Key.xmlText EQ 'Employer__c'>
    <cfset employer = keyValue[i].Value.xmlText>
</cfif>
<cfif keyValue[i].Key.xmlText EQ 'Primary_EmailAddress_EmailAddress'>
    <cfset email = keyValue[i].Value.xmlText>
</cfif>
<cfif keyValue[i].Key.xmlText EQ '_Default_PhoneNumber_PhoneNumber'>
    <cfset phone = keyValue[i].Value.xmlText>
</cfif>
<cfset chapterOfficer = {
    aName = #memberName#,
    bPositionName = #positionName#,
    cMemberGuid = #memberGuid#,
    dCompany = #employer#,
    eEmail = #email#,
    fPhone = #phone#
    } />
</cfloop>
```

Which works great for a single member. Dumping "chapterOfficer" gives me everything I need. My thought was build a bunch of structs for each officer and place them in an array, chapterOfficers, which I would then loop through to build my page:

```
<cfif structKeyExists(chapterOfficer, "aName")>
    <cfset arrayAppend(chapterOfficers, chapterOfficer)>
</cfif>
```

I placed this code at then end of the struct creator, just before the close of the loop. I do not understand the results, as it puts over 8500 structs in the array. Some structs have no entries, some have partial ones, some are repeats of previous ones, some have one officer's email and another one's phone -- arrgghh! What I was trying to do was, for every iteration of the loop, test for the existence of the key/value pairs I need for my page, add them to a newly created struct, and add the struct to an existing array.

There are indeed thousands of lines in the XML result I am working with, but only 10 officers. I am not sure why 8500 weird structs are being created -- a struct should not be added to the array unless the key "aName" exists, which should not happen unless a value for #memberName# is being defined on any given pass of the loop. Any struct created should only contain the key / value pairs I am assigning to it.

But that is not at all what is happening. I am pretty sure I am making this way more complicated than it actually is, but it really has me stumped. I would *greatly* appreciate any tips, advice, suggestions, pointers -- thank you all so much in advance for your help!

Comment: Only half read this, but sounds like you need a `<cfset chapterOfficer = {} />` after you have done the `ArrayAppend` (still inside the cfif) to reset the struct, otherwise the old data sticks around and causes the weirdness. (Also, you don't need those hashes in the struct definition.)

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody is interested, I got a working solution by breaking the SOAP envelope containing the query into two parts, on two different pages.

The first envelope queries for the committee info (member name, ID, position) and loops over the resulting XML to load up a multi-dimensional array, which I then save as a session var. Then  takes me to another page where I get individual data (ID from the second table, email, phone), and a 2nd multi-dimensional array is created.

Each table outputs its information in a different order (of course), so I then loop over both arrays and sort them based on ID. I then loop over them again to output to the page.

I end up with a nice listing of name, position, email and phone number. It works, but what a headache! Surely there is a better way to do this...