# CFHTTP Response - Set XML values in variables

Tags: xml, coldfusion, xml-parsing, cfhttp

I'm making a CFHTTP request which is returning the following XML in the fileContent:

```
<login>
    <success>1</success>
    <player>
        <id>123456</id>
        <nucleusId>28736389714</nucleusId>
        <email>myemail@email.com</email>
        <preferredPersona>
            <id>19842082</id>
            <gamertag>MyGamerTag1</gamertag>
            <platform>360</platform>
        </preferredPersona>
    </player>
</login>
```

What I'm looking to do is declare ColdFusion variables for:

- player -> id
- player -> nucleusID
- player -> email
- player -> preferredPersona -> id
- player -> preferredPersona -> gamertag
- player -> preferredPersona -> platform

I've had a read around all morning but am still none the wiser on how I'd achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

So all you need to do is convert some XML to a coldfusion structure?

- http://www.anujgakhar.com/2007/11/05/coldfusion-xml-to-struct/
- http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1039-Ask-Ben-Iterating-Over-A-ColdFusion-XML-Document.htm
- http://www.cflib.org/udf/flattenXmlToStruct
- [ColdFusion - how to loop through XML output and adding to struct or array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705162/coldfusion-how-to-loop-through-xml-output-and-adding-to-struct-or-array)

I'd probably just do it like

```
<cfsavecontent variable="myXML">
<login>
    <success>1</success>
    <player>
        <id>123456</id>
        <nucleusId>28736389714</nucleusId>
        <email>myemail@email.com</email>
        <preferredPersona>
            <id>19842082</id>
            <gamertag>MyGamerTag1</gamertag>
            <platform>360</platform>
        </preferredPersona>
    </player>
</login> 
</cfsavecontent>

<cfset myXML = XMLParse(myXML)>
<cfset stuPlayer = {}>
<cfset stuPlayer.ID = myXML.login.player.ID.XmlText>
<cfset stuPlayer.nucleusID = myXML.login.player.nucleusID.XmlText>
... etc
<cfdump var="#stuPlayer#">
```

Answer (score 0):

Over and above Duncan's answer, it seems you could probably step back, and get yourself up to speed understanding/using XML in ColdFusion before you look at any implementation stuff.

- [The XML document object](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec133ba-7fd8.html)
- [Using an XML object](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec133ba-7fe6.html)
- [Functions for XML object management](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-78e5.html)
- [XML document object management reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-78e3.html)
- [Using XML and ColdFusion queries](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec133ba-7fbe.html) - demonstrates transformation techniques.

It's always best to read and understand the docs before trying to use some part of CFML's functionality.